# Accesing nodejs process.env variables in CRA prod build in containerized Kubernetes deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables, create-react-app, production-environment

I have created a [production build](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build) from [CRA](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) in it there is a connection string    [image: conn string original]
that when trying to get it into kubernetes via a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/#services), I set it up in this way :
[image: connstring translated]
The minified version prod ready of CRA translate it to this
[image]

`"http://"+Object({NODE_ENV:"production",PUBLIC_URL:""}).APISERVER_SERVICE_HOST+":"+Object({NODE_ENV:"production",PUBLIC_URL:""}).APISERVER_SERVICE_PORT`

`process.env` does not have any container ENV.
Could it be that the build just "baked-in" the env variables at build time and that's the reason the client sees them as strings rather that key/values while in the pod ?

The goal is to access the **api url** utilize **env** variables within the container via process.env.VARIABLE_NAME once the pod are deployed

The thing is when it gets deployed the uri is undefined [image] meaning the code is unable to convert/detect/translate **proccess.env.VARIABLE** to its value
Even `console.log(process.env)` returns `undefined`

If I get into the pod/container and check env variables they are working correctly 
[image: container ENV variables]
[image: env variables via node and shell]

Why am I not getting the values of env variables in my build?
Do I have to build it at a certain time?
What am I missing?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:10 as build-deps
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build
RUN echo $APISERVER_SERVICE_HOST

FROM nginx:1.12-alpine
RUN  apk update && apk add nodejs 
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY conf /etc/nginx 
COPY --from=build-deps /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN echo $APISERVER_SERVICE_HOST
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Service and Deployment kubernetes**

```
#Service for readable
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: readable-deployment
  name: readable
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    run: readable-deployment
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}  


---
#Deployment for Readable
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    run: readable-deployment
  name: readable-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: readable-deployment
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: readable-deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: gcr.io/kuberneteseval/readable:latest-01
        name: readable-deployment
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Comment: Post the actual text of your Docker file for a better chance of someone helping you.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Thanks for your comment.. what text? when I run docker images both API and CLIENT work ok even without modifying the URL string the problem is when doing the deploy to kubernetes

Comment: You are not going to see that environment variable at build time unless you set then with  --build-arg.

Comment: Enter the docker file contents as quoted text like everyone else does!  kubernetes let's you set env variables.

Comment: You;ve been talking about getting those env variables in the browser all this time??!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, This is for a [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) production [build](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#npm-run-build-or-yarn-build)

As of today `Aug 24 2018` there is still a [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2353) for this and how it should be done.

No matter what I did the API url was always a "**key string**" and not the value of the **env** variables.

What I did: (just a workaround and **does not** get service variables at runtime)

- I created `.env.production` file  and added `REACT_APP_SERVICE_HOST` and `REACT_APP_SERVICE_PORT`
  The problem with this is that at docker build time in my local machine there is no way of getting the values of the cluster service variables hence you would have to set the values manually. like so: `REACT_APP_APISERVER_SERVICE_HOST=35.15.5.0`and `REACT_APP_APISERVER_SERVICE_PORT=3008`

Other Alternatives:

- I try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653931/react-configuration-file-for-post-deployment-settings/51663697#51663697) Apparently it does grab the services variables. Couldn't make it work for me
- I also tried Ejecting and use the [Environment plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) which is a shorthand of the **define Plugin** used by CRA but again your not gonna have access to the services variables at build time...