# How to make configuration file to store APIs in React

Tags: reactjs

I want to store APIs in configuration file so when I deployed this on Development or on Production I just have to change the url on config file not in all js file.
But I don't know how to use configuration file in react.js

I tried using react-global-configuration but didn't  got any results !
Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React configuration file for post deployment settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653931/react-configuration-file-for-post-deployment-settings)

Comment: @Maelig Both the issues are different.

Comment: as I understand you want to separate your dev and prod configuration ?

Comment: @Maelig yes what you understood is correct but issue in that is quite different.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the npm package [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).

You create a `.env` file in the root of your repository, and this package helps your project access any variable that's inside your `.env` file. You just need to:

```
npm install dotenv
```

Then you add this line to your App.js

`require('dotenv').config()`

and you're good to go!

Example:

```
> cat .env
DB_HOST="https://myserver.herokuapp.com"
```

To access the variable's name, you just have to call `process.env.DB_HOST` in your code.

**NOTE:**

If your project has been created using `create-react-app`, then you must name the variables like this:

```
REACT_APP_DB_HOST="https://myserver.herokuapp.com"
```

and if you want to access it you use:

```
process.env.REACT_APP_DB_HOST
```

Comment: Thank you @josemartindev for your help...but this didn't worked.

Comment: @ShwetaRathi why it didn't work? It works perfectly for me and for more than 4million users that download weekly this npm package